# VS2010 - Should I use ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I would like to create a Internal(LAN) Web Application. The App and DB will be under same Server. I need some idea should I use MVC ?

Thanks and Best Regards
Dylan Heng

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC is where Microsoft is currently placing its development emphasis. ASP.NET MVC also has the advantages of greater maintainability thanks to a framework-enforced separation of concerns, however it does have a learning curve that takes some time to get used to.

The fact your database is local is of no significance.

Use Web Forms if you're already familiar with that platform and you need to build something quickly, but if this is an internal application and it's likely development and maintenance will handled by other people in the distant future then I would strongly advise using ASP.NET MVC instead of WebForms.

Comment: To add to this, I would suggest it would also depend on the complexity of the project (a simple CRUD - CReate/Update/Delete - application created for an internal audience would be built much faster in Web Forms), its function (rich User Inferface display is generally better done in MVC as it is easier to work with JavaScript and gives much greater control over HTML markup), and the familiarity of the developer(s) with HMTL and the web (Web Forms offers much less of a learning curve as it abstracts away to a large extent). The question doesn't give enough detail.